# Иллюстрирует ли пример функцию О-большое?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, сортировка

Я человек далёкий от математики, но понадобилось разобраться с функцией О-большое. Я попытался написать на python пример, который иллюстрировал бы эту функцию и при этом был бы интуитивно понятен постороннему человеку.

Как видите, в качестве "подопытной" функции я использовать функцию сортировки массива вставками (insertion). Она имеет log N сложность, в чём можно убедиться, проанализировав вывод консоли.

Скажите пожалуйста, получилось ли проиллюстрировать О-большое? Мой код ниже, является хорошим примером? Можно ли его улучшить или исправить?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from random import randint

def insertion(data):
    for index_r in range(1, len(data)):
        value_r = data[index_r]
        index_l = index_r - 1

        while index_l >= 0:
            if value_r < data[index_l]:
                data[index_l+1] = data[index_l]
                data[index_l] = value_r
                index_l -= 1
            else:
                break

    return data


def O(N):
    for n in (range(N)):
        arr = [randint(1, n) for i in range(n)]

        start_time = time.time()
        insertion(arr)
        final_time = (time.time() - start_time)

        print('X-axis: {0}, Y-axis: {1}'.format(n, final_time))


O(100000)
```

[LIVE DEMO здесь](https://ideone.com/IhHFEp)

Comment: `Она имеет log N сложность, в чём можно убедиться` Увы, не имеет. Нельзя убедиться.

Comment: если придумаете [сортировку сложности `log N`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts), то сразу патентируйте - разбогатеете ;-)